# Espresso test fails after successful click and blocking for 60 seconds

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have tried using Espresso testing framework and wrote a simple test.

Nothing fancy there, just this code:

```
onView(withId(R.id.login_button_stub)).perform(click());
```

Test runs fine on a Nexus 5 device and Genymotion with Android 5.0, but fails on Android Emulator 4.x, 5.0, Genymotion 2.3, 4.x and LG G2 with Android 4.x.

On all these devices/emulators/simulators, the button is clicked and its action executed (going to another screen in my case). The problem is it blocks in `perform` on some devices. This ends with a nice exception after 60 seconds:

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click' on view 'with id: com.vielengames.mock:id/login_button_stub'.
    ...
    Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Looped for 3544 iterations over 60 SECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed .
    ...
```

Note that there is no info about what conditions failed. Looking at Espresso source code, there should be a comma-separated list of issues.

Here is the full code: [TestCase.java](https://github.com/mg6maciej/VielenGamesAndroidClient/blob/feature/espresso_tests/app/src/androidTestMock/java/com/vielengames/ui/NotLoggedOnTestCase.java).

and full stacktrace:

```
I/TestRunner﹕ android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click' on view 'with id: com.vielengames.mock:id/login_button_stub'.
        at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83)
        at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:70)
        at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:53)
        at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:185)
        at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115)
        at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87)
        at com.vielengames.ui.NotLoggedOnTestCase.testLoggedOnAfterLoginClick(NotLoggedOnTestCase.java:19)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
        at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
        at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
        at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:133)
        at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.DelegatingTestResult.runProtected(DelegatingTestResult.java:90)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
        at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidTestResult.run(AndroidTestResult.java:49)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
        at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.NonLeakyTestSuite$NonLeakyTest.run(NonLeakyTestSuite.java:63)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
        at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.DelegatingTestSuite.run(DelegatingTestSuite.java:103)
        at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidTestSuite.run(AndroidTestSuite.java:63)
        at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:90)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
        at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:270)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
 Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Looped for 3544 iterations over 60 SECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed .
        at android.support.test.espresso.IdlingPolicy.handleTimeout(IdlingPolicy.java:61)
        at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:471)
        at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:402)
        at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectMotionEvent(UiControllerImpl.java:226)
        at android.support.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:135)
        at android.support.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendUp(MotionEvents.java:118)
        at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.sendSingleTap(Tap.java:135)
        at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.access$100(Tap.java:35)
        at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:40)
        at android.support.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:98)
        at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was a bug in my app code, where `SwipeRefreshLayout` animated itself indefinitely. Due to [a bug in this component](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77712), the refresh state was not even showing.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was driving me nuts; I had a spinning animation running in a previous Fragment that was never cleared, so the app wasn't idle and Espresso tests would hang.

Actually a great feature now I realise, as it forces the developer to be tidy with animations and background actions.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! In my case, OffsetChangeListener of AppBarLayout called constantly where it customizes the AppBar with an Animation

Comment: i got the  similar issue ,but in my case its button with animated progressbar attached to  it,any clue to that

Comment: My case is similar; caused by a CountDownTimer.